# ReactJS Error Nothing Returned from Render with Const in Class Render()

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a component that checks the length of a prop, slices a string and displays a link if it exceeds a certain amount of characters and then shows/hides the full length on the link click. I feel like my setup is halfway to achieving the functionality described, but I am running into an issue with how I configured my link component. I am still learning React and am not sure if I need to wrap my link in `TextExpandButton` in a `return()` statement or if it stems from a different issue.

**Here is the full error:**

```
Uncaught Error: TextExpandButton(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

**Here is the full code:**

```
import React from 'react';

//Annotation Card - Body
export default class Body extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { showFullText: false, characterLimit: 5, expandButtonText: "Show More..." };
    }

    expandFullText(){
        this.setState({
            showFullText: true,
            characterLimit: this.props.discovery.length,
            expandButtonText: "Show Less"
        });
    }

    render() {
        //Annotation Card - Body - Text Expand Link
        const TextExpandButton = props => {
            <a href="#" onClick={this.expandFullText}>this.props.buttonText</a>
        }

        const partialText = this.props.discovery.slice(0, this.state.characterLimit);

        var textExpandButton;
        if(this.props.discovery.length > this.state.characterLimit) { 
            textExpandButton = <TextExpandButton buttonText={this.state.expandFullText} />;
        } else { 
            return null; 
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{partialText}</p>
                {textExpandButton}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share code where you imported the component?

Comment: Can you please import TextExpandButton component?

Comment: Sorry The `TextExpandButton` is located just below the `render()`. Maybe that is my problem?

Comment: You are missing a return statement in `TextExpandButton`. Either get rid of the curly braces or put a `return` before `<a href='#' onClick...>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something from the functional component.

**Component:**

```
import React from 'react';

//Annotation Card - Body
export default class Body extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = { showFullText: false, characterLimit: 5, expandButtonText: "Show More..." };
    }

    expandFullText(){
        this.setState({
            showFullText: true,
            characterLimit: this.props.discovery.length,
            expandButtonText: "Show Less"
        });
    }

    render() {
        //Annotation Card - Body - Text Expand Link
        const TextExpandButton = props => {
            return <a href="#" onClick={this.expandFullText}>this.props.buttonText</a>
        }

        const partialText = this.props.discovery.slice(0, this.state.characterLimit);

        var textExpandButton;
        if(this.props.discovery.length > this.state.characterLimit) { 
            textExpandButton = <TextExpandButton buttonText={this.expandFullText} />;
        } else { 
            return null; 
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <p>{partialText}</p>
                {textExpandButton}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Or you can do:

```
const TextExpandButton = props => <a href="#" onClick={this.expandFullText}>this.props.buttonText</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. Simple solution that I overlooked. Do I also need to pass down `expandFullText()` with a property on `<TextExpandButton />` or is it global where it sits within the code?

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your code

First thing TextExpandButton is a functional component so it should be outside your class component but not inside render

Remove below code from Body component

```
const TextExpandButton = props => {
    <a href="#" onClick={this.expandFullText}>this.props.buttonText</a>
}
```

Place that outside class component

```
export const TextExpandButton = props => {
    return <a href="#" onClick={props.buttonText}>show more...</a>
}
```

And change

```
textExpandButton = <TextExpandButton buttonText={this.state.expandFullText} />;
```

To in your Body component

```
textExpandButton = <TextExpandButton buttonText={this.expandFullText} />;
```

Comment: This makes sense, but the `{this.state.expandFullText}` isn't working. Should it be `this.expandFullText`?